# Matlab install error: Simulink 3D Animation Toolbox

Tags: software-installation, java, matlab

I'm trying to install Matlab 8.0.1 (R2013a) on Ubuntu13.10 64bit.

There was some problem when I installed all the packages (inclusive of **Simulink 3D Animation Toolbox**) and other packages preceding it installed without issues. However when it came to the Simulink package,I got an error that read

```
The following error was detected while installing sl3d_glnxa64:
archive is not a ZIP archive
Would you like to retry installing sl3d_glnxa64?
If you press No, the installer will exit without completing the installation.  More information can be found at /tmp/mathworks_root.log
```

The `/tmp/mathworks_root.log` has some java errors. Some googling told me this was because of insufficient `/tmp` space, and hence I tried created a subdirectory in my home folder and installed using `./install -tmpdir /path/to/home/subdir`

The temp directory was recognised and accepted (as recorded in the log file). but still I get the same error. I was able to deselect the package and install Matlab, which otherwise runs fine.
How do I in install the Simulink toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this temporary solution unless you really need this 3D animation toolbox.

Start from beginning

Choose Custom installation instead of ( Typical )

Un-check this toolbox ( simulink 3D animation ) which is creating problem.

The proceed further.

All the best :)

Comment: that is what I did to install rest of Matlab. My question is how do I get the problematic toolbox working